# Proxy in Rabbitmq Java Client

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Is there any way to set a proxy to a RabbitMQ Java client?

```
package com.rabbitmq;

import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.MessageProperties;

public class SendToRabbitMQ {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "observation_queue";

    public static void sendObservation(String observation) {
        try {
            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.setHost("x.x.x.x");
            factory.setUsername("test");
            factory.setVirtualHost("test_vh");
            factory.setPassword("test");
            Connection con = factory.newConnection();
            Channel channel = con.createChannel();
            channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
            channel.basicPublish( "", QUEUE_NAME,
                    MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN,
                    observation.getBytes());
            System.out.println(" Ovservation Sent '" + observation + "'");
            channel.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

I want to set a proxy for this Connection.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup a SOCKS Proxy.

see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: It also needs to be noted that the proxy server itself needs to support SOCKS protocol, and not all proxies do (e.g. i-Filter).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a proxy, by mean of system properties, as described in the link given in the first answer, but be aware that it will be valid for the whole JVM. If there are rules to filter the traffic, your database connections or other could be filtered.

If you have found how to deal with a proxy with the Proxy object, you're welcome to explain in an answer to your own question ! I am looking for that !